# Make me a s'more!

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Make me a [s'more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%27more)! I tell you the width, the amount of graham cracker, the amount of chocolate, and the amount of marshmallow. An example:

Input:

Width: `10`
Graham: `3`
Chocolate: `2`
Marshmallow: `1`.

Output:

```
GGGGGGGGGG
GGGGGGGGGG
GGGGGGGGGG
CCCCCCCCCC
CCCCCCCCCC
MMMMMMMMMM
GGGGGGGGGG
GGGGGGGGGG
GGGGGGGGGG
```

Is it *that easy?* Um... yes.

Note that the input should be a list of arguments to a function or a program, not a string. You might choose the first being Width, then Graham, but any order is fine.

[Full test cases if you are interested.](https://pastebin.com/dNzS3FgY)

## Stack snippet (for testing, etc.)

This is to test the output.

```js
var smore = function(width, graham, chocolate, marshmallow){
 return ("G".repeat(width) + "\n").repeat(graham) + 
 ("C".repeat(width) + "\n").repeat(chocolate) + 
 ("M".repeat(width) + "\n").repeat(marshmallow) + 
 ("G".repeat(width) + "\n").repeat(graham);
};
Snippetify(smore);
```

```html
<script src="https://programmer5000.com/snippetify.min.js"></script>
Width: <input type = "number">
Graham: <input type = "number">
Chocolate: <input type = "number">
Marshmallow: <input type = "number">
<button>Try it out!</button>
<pre data-output></pre>
```

## Notes:

- You may include a trailing newline on the end of the last line. You may also use a `\` instead of a newline.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf).
- Any questions? Comment below:

Comment: I edited out your Let Me Google That For You link. It really wasn't funny.

Comment: can the output be a matrix of characters?

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista yes.

Comment: Some answers are assuming flexible input order and format (as usual in PPCG), but the challenge seems to require a specific order and rule out strings (not sure what that means). Can you clarify?

Comment: @LuisMendo, you can use any input order desired.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. You should then reword the sentence _the input should be a list of arguments to a function or a program, not a string, with the first being Width, then Graham, etc_. Personally I would say something like "Input format is flexible as usual"

Comment: @LuisMendo added. If there is anything else you think should be added, feel free to edit that in.

Comment: @programmer5000 but why? If they downvoted, it's 90% likely it's because they think it's a boring and trivial challenge. Furthermore, it's quite rude to tell people to explain or retract. They have the right to downvote without comment.

Comment: [S'more what?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XlddDZkkxCc)

Comment: @EngineerToast A gram of what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
ṁ4“GCMG”x×Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9wZ6PJo4Y57s6@7o8a5lYcnh75//9/Yx0FIx0Fw/@GBgA)

#### How it works

```
ṁ4“GCMG”x×Y  Main link. Left argument: g, c, m. Right argument: w

ṁ4           Mold 4; repeat g, c, m until length 4 is reached. Yields [g, c, m, g].
  “GCMG”x    Repeat 'G' g times, then 'C' c times, then 'M' m times, and finally
             'G' g times. This yields a string.
         ×   Multiply each character w times. This is essentially a bug, but
             Jelly's × behaves like Python's * (and vectorizes), so it can be
             abused for character repetition.
          Y  Join, separating by linefeeds.
```

Answer (score 13):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>73</s> 48 bytes

```python
lambda w,g,c,m:zip(*['G'*g+'C'*c+'M'*m+'G'*g]*w)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#LYvLCsIwEADv/YoFD5vHIlZvQk8ePPkF1kOMpq6YBzGl4s9HaL0Nw4zr@voy/nozMNFAlvz@y0moMx5RDRoPqKzGEyqvZ3NRk6zccUhjEbJZpcyhgBOKZbMw9gHXz8hBeJMELkxzISX8hzgW8KZk/kB0YB8mG1vu@V3bDe1oS@0P)

Creates a transposed version of the answer, than transposes it to the correct format with `zip(*l)`

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>21</s> <s>19</s> 19 bytes

```
"GCMG"S×|D«‚øvy`.D»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@6/k7uzrrhR8eHqNy6HVjxpmHd5RVpmg53Jo9///hgZcxlxGXIYA)

-2 thanks to my oversight and Emigna.

```
"GCMG"S×            # Push GCMG, separate, duplicate n times.
        |D«         # Push rest of inputs, doubled.
           ‚ø       # Wrap GCMG array and input array, then zip them into pairs.
             vy`.D» # For each pair, print n of G/C/M/G.
```

(See Emigna's answer, it's better: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/116787/59376)

Comment: You seem to have accidentally left a `©` in there.

Comment: You could also replace `¬¸` with `D` as the extra elements are lost when you zip.

Comment: @Emigna I both like and hate that functionality.

Comment: Yes, it's often very annoying but now and then (like now) it becomes useful :)

Comment: `"GCMG"` can be `…GCMĆ` for -1 (although I've also just posted [a 14-byter with a different approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/198628/52210)).

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>17</s> 16 bytes

1 bytes saved thanks to *carusocomputing*.

```
"GCMG"S×vy²Nè.D»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@6/k7uzrrhR8eHpZ5aFNfodX6Lkc2v3/v6EBV7SxjpGOYSwA)

Input order is `W, [G,C,M]`

**Explanation**

`10, [3,2,1]` used as example.

```
"GCMG"S           # push the list ['G','C','M','G']
       ×          # repeat each W times
                  # STACK: ['GGGGGGGGGG', 'CCCCCCCCCC', 'MMMMMMMMMM', 'GGGGGGGGGG']
        v         # for each [string, index] y,N in the list
          ²Nè     # get the amount of layers at index N from the [G,C,M] list
         y   .D   # duplicate the string y that many times
               »  # join strings by newlines
```

Comment: `"GCMG"S×vy²Nè.D»` wonder-twin powers, activate! Form of, 05AB1E code! Also, arguments get swapped, but it's still 16.

Comment: @carusocomputing: It has the benefit of not leaving unprinted crap on the stack, but it seems similarly irreducible to me.

Comment: It's still 1 byte less and will beat your tie with MATL ;).

Comment: @carusocomputing: Oooh, when did that happen? I was sure it was 17 when I saw it. Nice! ;)

Comment: I often post stupid stuff and make edits to it 1 minute after I realize I'm being an idiot.

Comment: `"GCMG"` can be `…GCMĆ` for -1 (although I've also just posted [a 14-byter with a different approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/198628/52210)).

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), 71 bytes

```
(W,G,C,M)=>[...'GCMG'].map(X=>`${X.repeat(W)}
`.repeat(eval(X))).join``
```

Woohoo, beat 3 other JavaScript answers!

```js
f=
(W,G,C,M)=>[...'GCMG'].map(X=>`${X.repeat(W)}
`.repeat(eval(X))).join``

console.log(
    f(10, 3, 2, 1)
)
```

Comment: Nice, very nice - gets my vote.

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 17 bytes

```
'GCMG'iK:)Y"!liX"
```

Input format is: first input `[G, C, M]`, second input `W`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@6/u7uzrrp7pbaUZqaSYkxmh9P9/tLGCkYJhLJehAQA)

#### Explanation with example

Consider inputs `[3 2 1]`  and `10`.

```
'GCMG' % Push this string
       % STACK: 'GCMG'
i      % Take first input: array of three numbers
       % STACK: 'GCMG', [3 2 1]
K:     % Push [1 2 3 4]
       % STACK: 'GCMG', [3 2 1], [1 2 3 4]
)      % Index (modular, 1-based). This repeats the first entry of the input array
       % STACK: 'GCMG', [3 2 1 3]
Y"     % Run-length decoding
       % STACK: 'GGGCCMGGG'
!      % Transpose. Gives a column vector of chars
       % STACK: ['G'; 'G'; 'G'; 'C'; 'C'; 'M'; 'G'; 'G'; 'G']
l      % Push 1
       % STACK: ['G'; 'G'; 'G'; 'C'; 'C'; 'M'; 'G'; 'G'; 'G'], 1
i      % Take second input: number
       % STACK: ['G'; 'G'; 'G'; 'C'; 'C'; 'M'; 'G'; 'G'; 'G'], 1, 10
X"     % Repeat the specified numbers of times along first and second dimensions
       % STACK: ['GGGGGGGGGG';'GGGGGGGGGG';'GGGGGGGGGG';'CCCCCCCCCC';...;'GGGGGGGGGG']
       % Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 6):

### [C#](http://csharppad.com/gist/6c2b7ee2d9f3df79de6e4da1950ee4ea), 204 bytes

---

#### Golfed

```cs
(w,g,c,m)=>{string G="\n".PadLeft(++w,'G'),C="\n".PadLeft(w,'C'),M="\n".PadLeft(w,'M'),o="".PadLeft(g,'G');o+="".PadLeft(m,'M')+"".PadLeft(c,'C')+o;return o.Replace("G",G).Replace("C",C).Replace("M",M);};
```

---

#### Ungolfed

```cs
( w, g, c, m ) => {
   string
      G = "\n".PadLeft( ++w, 'G' ),
      C = "\n".PadLeft( w, 'C' ),
      M = "\n".PadLeft( w, 'M' ),
      o = "".PadLeft( g, 'G' );
      
   o +=
      "".PadLeft( m, 'M' ) +
      "".PadLeft( c, 'C' ) +
      o;
   
   return o
      .Replace( "G", G )
      .Replace( "C", C )
      .Replace( "M", M );
};
```

---

#### Ungolfed readable

```cs
// Function with 4 parameters
//   w : Width
//   g : Graham
//   c : Chocolate
//   m : Marshmallow
( w, g, c, m ) => {
   
   // Initialization of vars with the contents
   //    of each line, with a new line at the end
   string
      G = "\n".PadLeft( ++w, 'G' ),
      C = "\n".PadLeft( w, 'C' ),
      M = "\n".PadLeft( w, 'M' ),
      
      // Trick to reduce the byte count
      //   Initialize the output with n 'G's
      o = "".PadLeft( g, 'G' );
      
   // Add again n 'M's and n 'C's
   //   Append the 'G's at the end.
   o +=
      "".PadLeft( m, 'M' ) +
      "".PadLeft( c, 'C' ) +
      o;
   
   // Replce every instance of 'G'/'C'/'M'
   //    with the full line
   return o
      .Replace( "G", G )
      .Replace( "C", C )
      .Replace( "M", M );
};
```

---

#### Full code

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Namespace {
   class Program {
      static void Main( String[] args ) {
         Func<Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, String> f = ( w, g, c, m ) => {
            string
               G = "\n".PadLeft( ++w, 'G' ),
               C = "\n".PadLeft( w, 'C' ),
               M = "\n".PadLeft( w, 'M' ),
               o = "".PadLeft( g, 'G' );
               
            o +=
               "".PadLeft( m, 'M' ) +
               "".PadLeft( c, 'C' ) +
               o;
            
            return o
               .Replace( "G", G )
               .Replace( "C", C )
               .Replace( "M", M );
         };

         List<Tuple<Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32>>
            testCases = new List<Tuple<Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32>>() {
               new Tuple<Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32>( 1, 1, 1, 1 ),
               new Tuple<Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32>( 1, 1, 1, 2 ),
               new Tuple<Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32>( 1, 1, 2, 1 ),
               //
               // ...
               //
               // The link above contains the code ready to run
               //    and with every test from the pastebin link
               //
               // Yes, it contains 342 tests ready to run.
               //
               // I can barely fit every test on a 1080p screen...
               //    ... and there's 6 tests per line... Jebus...
               //
            };
         
         foreach( var testCase in testCases ) {
            Console.WriteLine( $"Input:\nWidth: {testCase.Item1,3} Graham: {testCase.Item2,3} Chocolate: {testCase.Item3,3} Marshmellow: {testCase.Item4,3}\nOutput:\n{f( testCase.Item1, testCase.Item2, testCase.Item3, testCase.Item4 )}\n" );
         }

         Console.ReadLine();
      }
   }
}
```

---

#### Releases

- **v1.0** - `204 bytes` - Initial solution.

---

#### Notes

- [Looking for a picture of my *beautiful* test screen?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OERg.png)
- On a second thought, CSharpPad can't handle those tests, [here's a version with fewer tests](http://csharppad.com/gist/ea843ff852f907176d8a3eb86cf93b3a)

Comment: Appreciated! :D

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, 47 bytes

```
->w,g,c,m{puts r=[?G*w]*g,[?C*w]*c,[?M*w]*m,r}
```

thanks to ventero

## Ruby, 51 bytes

```
->w,g,c,m{(?G*g+?C*c+?M*m+?G*g).chars{|i|puts i*w}}
```

Call like this:

```
f=->w,g,c,m{(?G*g+?C*c+?M*m+?G*g).chars{|i|puts i*w}}

f[10,3,2,1]
```

Comment: `->w,g,c,m{puts r=[?G*w]*g,[?C*w]*c,[?M*w]*m,r}` is a bit shorter

Answer (score 4):

## C, <s>108</s> 105 bytes

*Thanks to @Quentin for saving 3 bytes!*

```
#define F(i,c)for(;i--;puts(""))for(j=w;j--;)putchar(c);
i,j;f(w,g,c,m){i=g;F(i,71)F(c,67)F(m,77)F(g,71)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#HcxBCsMgEIXhvacY0s0MTKC2UBeSbe4RbLQjaEuSkkXI2a32bX74Fq9cnrOXPMOIwo78e0ErfW8/323FrqO/xGG3sSJVda9pQUdWCUfrcefAjhMdMgTbPoymER0/TE1i0xIankXyBmmSjKQOBXUe9ZXhznBj0PXxLD8)

Comment: `#define F(i,c)for(;i--;puts(""))for(j=w;j--;)putchar(c);` saves three bytes :)

Comment: @Quentin Thanks! I wonder why I missed that in the first place :)

Answer (score 4):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 49 bytes

```powershell
$a,$b=$args;0..2+0|%{,("$('GCM'[$_])"*$a)*$b[$_]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@6@SqKOSZKuSWJRebG2gp2ekbVCjWq2joaSioe7u7KserRIfq6mkpZKoqaWSBOLU/v//39Dgv/F/o/@GAA)

Takes input as four command-line arguments, `width graham chocolate marshmallow`, stores the first into `$a` and the rest into `$b` (implicitly as an array). Loops from over the range `0,1,2,0`. Each loop, we index into string `GCM`, re-cast that `char` as a string, and multiply it out by `$a` (the width), and then using the comma-operator `,`, turns that into an array by multiplying the appropriate index of `$b` (i.e., how many layers). Those resultant string arrays are all left on the pipeline and output is implicit, with a newline between elements.

Answer (score 3):

### Batch, 146 bytes

```
@set s=
@for /l %%i in (1,1,%1)do @call set s=G%%s%%
@for %%w in (%2.%s% %3.%s:G=C% %4.%s:G=M% %2.%s%)do @for /l %%i in (1,1,%%~nw)do @echo%%~xw
```

Relies on the obscure behaviour of `echo` in that it can often ignore the symbol between `echo` and the text to be echoed to collapse the four loops into a nested loop.

Answer (score 3):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 22 bytes

```
éGÄÀäjMoC
MÀÄkÀÄHdêÀP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@394pfvhlsMNh5dk@eY7c/lKA5kt2SDCI@XwqsMNAf///zf@b/jf6L@hAQA)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: e947 c4c0 e46a 4d6f 430a 4d1b c0c4 6bc0  .G...jMoC.M...k.
00000010: c448 64ea c050                           .Hd..P
```

Input order is

```
Graham, Marshmallow, Chocolate, Width
```

Explanation:

```
éG                  " Insert 'G'
  Ä                 " Duplicate this line
   Àäj              " *arg1* times, duplicate this line and the line below it
      M             " Move to the middle line
       o            " Open up a newline, and enter insert mode
        C<cr>M<esc> " Insert 'C\nM'
ÀÄ                  " Make *arg2* copies of this line (Marshmallow)
  k                 " Move up one line
   ÀÄ               " Make *arg3* copies of this line (Chocolate)
     H              " Move to the first line
      dê            " Delete this column
        ÀP          " And paste it horizontally *arg4* times
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation?

Comment: @programmer5000 Sure! See my edit

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 14 bytes

Code:

```
…GCM‚øü×¬)˜S×»
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@/@oYZm7s@@jhlmHdxzec3j6oTWap@cEA@nd//9HG@soGOkoGMZyGRoAAA)

Explanation:

```
…GCM              # Push the string "GCM"
    ‚             # Wrap with the input
     ø            # Transpose the array
      ü×          # Compute the string product of each element (['A', 3] --> 'AAA')
        ¬)˜       # Get the last element and append to the list
           S      # Split the list
            ×     # Vectorized string multiplication with the second input
             »    # Join by newlines and implicitly print
```

Answer (score 3):

## Excel, 104 bytes

Oh, boy! A formula that requires line breaks.

```
=REPT(REPT("G",A1)&"
",A2)&REPT(REPT("C",A1)&"
",A3)&REPT(REPT("M",A1)&"
",A4)&REPT(REPT("G",A1)&"
",A2)
```

`A1` has Width
`A2` has Graham
`A3` has Chocolate
`A4` has Mallow

---

If pre-formatting is allowed, then you can format the cell for Vertical Text and shorten the formula to 65 bytes:

```
=REPT(REPT("G",A2)&REPT("C",A3)&REPT("M",A4)&REPT("G",A2)&"
",A1)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“GCM”ẋ"ṁ4Fẋ€Y
```

A dyadic program. Inputs are: `[Graham's, Chocolates, Marshmallows]`, `Width`.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@oYY67s@@jhrkPd3UrPdzZaOIGZDxqWhP5////aGMdIx3D2P@GBl/z8nWTE5MzUgE)**

#### How?

```
“GCM”ẋ"ṁ4Fẋ€Y - Main link: [g,c,m], w    e.g. [1,2,1], 2
“GCM”         - literal ['G', 'C', 'M']
      "       - zip that and [g,c,m] with the dyadic operation:
     ẋ        -     repeat list               [['G'],['C','C'],['M']]
       ṁ4     - mould like [1,2,3,4]          [['G'],['C','C'],['M'],['G']]
         F    - flatten                       ['G','C','C','M','G']
          ẋ€  - repeat €ach w times           [['G','G'],['C','C'],['C','C'],['M','M'],['G','G']]
            Y - join with line feeds          ['G','G','\n','C','C','\n','C','C','\n','M','M','\n','G','G']
              - implicit print                GG
                                              CC
                                              CC
                                              MM
                                              GG
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <del>67</del>57 bytes

(Edit: now that matrices are allowed, no need to newline-join it.)

```python
def s(w,g,c,m):g=['G'*w]*g;print g+['C'*w]*c+['M'*w]*m+g
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 85 Bytes

```
for($m=$argv;$i++<4;)for($c=$m[_2342[$i]]*$m[1];$c;)echo$c--%$m[1]?"":"\n",_GCMG[$i];
```

or

```
for($m=$argv;$i++<4;)for($c=$m[_2342[$i]];$c--;)echo"\n".str_pad("",$m[1],_GCMG[$i]);
```

[Online Versions](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cff5f84dd5595e66e64ba0052ad5d010c97ba969)

## PHP, 96 Bytes

```
<?[$n,$w,$G,$C,$M]=$argv;for(;$i<4;$i++)for($t=${"$n[$i]"};$t--;)echo"\n".str_pad("",$w,$n[$i]);
```

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a8b9676c4d0c543ce552a1197933205118616e22)

Expanded

```
[$n,$w,$G,$C,$M]=$argv; # $argv[0] must contain a file beginning with "GCMG"
for(;$i<4;$i++) # Take the first 4 values of the filename
for($t=${"$n[$i]"};$t--;) # How many rows should be printed
echo"\n".str_pad("",$w,$n[$i]); # print $w times the actual letter
```

Answer (score 2):

## Swift, <s>138</s> <s>137</s> <s>134</s> 130 bytes

<sup>Saved 7 bytes thanks to ***@Kevin***</sup>

```
let f=String.init(repeating:count:)
let r={w,g,c,m in f(f("G",w)+"\n",g)+f(f("C",w)+"\n",c)+f(f("M",w)+"\n",m)+f(f("G",w)+"\n",g)}
```

Two functions that return the expected value: `f` is a helper function and `r` is the actual lamdba-like function that generates the output. ***Usage:*** `print(r(10,3,2,1))`

**[Check it out!](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/58f5b479da4eb37edb42a2ac)**

Comment: You can save several characters by just referencing the string initializer directly (`var f=String.init(repeating:count:);`). And it doesn't save you any characters but it doesn't cost any so they should both really be `let`.

Comment: And 3 more by dropping the explicit arguments in `r` (`let r={f(f("G",$0)+"\n",$1)+f(f("C",$0)+"\n",$2)+f(f("M",$0)+"\n",$3)+f(f("G",$0)+"\n",$1)}`)

Comment: @Kevin Thanks, I had no idea that you can initialise a value to something like this: `f=String.init(repeating:count:)`...

Comment: @Kevin when it comes to your second suggestion, it seems like it exceeds the number of bytes in UTF-8, checked the byte count on TIO, don't know why

Answer (score 2):

## C# (150 bytes)

```
void S(int w,int g,int c,int m){P(w,g,'G');P(w,c,'C');P(w,m,'M');P(w,g,'G');}void P(int w,int i,char c){while(i-->0)Console.Write("\n".PadLeft(w,c));}
```

Ungolfed:

```
void SMores(int w, int g, int c, int m)
{
    Print(w,g,'G');
    Print(w,c,'C');
    Print(w,m,'M');
    Print(w,g,'G');
}
void Print(int w, int i, char c)
{
    while(i-->0)
        Console.Write("\n".PadLeft(w,c));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## C, 90 bytes (based on [Steadybox's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/116782/30000))

Renamed the variables and exploited the stringification preprocessor operator to cut down on the macro parameters. I hope posting this idea as its own answer is fine :)

```
#define F(x)for(i=x;i--;puts(""))for(j=w;j--;)printf(#x);
i,j;f(w,G,C,M){F(G)F(C)F(M)F(G)}
```

[TIO link](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#HYzBCoMwEETv@Yqgl13YQG2PwZMQT36EtG7Z0KailgTEX2@aduDB8Bgm17eJJUzaQUJ@LSBtsmKMnd/bClWFf@nbaH2ROC8SNoY6oVVC3jJE6qmjAXcHPTroCgP@@pHLVD9HCYBqV7qEoTmRvpA@k27Kw5E/V36M9zWb@AU)

Comment: Would upvote, but hit vote limit :(

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 138 bytes

```java
String s(int w,int g,int c,int m){String b="";int i=-g-c,j;for(;i++<g+m;){for(j=0;j++<w;)b+=i<=-c|i>m?'G':i<=0?'C':'M';b+="\n";}return b;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#NU6xboMwFNzzFU8stoVBJN3y4kZRhk6dMiYdwKHoodhE2ARVlG8nhqY33NPdvZNO33Ln4ADDdPIt2QocJ@uhlzNXC@uFjRheH4WKIpwtUkmVaFnjd9NypDjeVbFBMcyyVhnWwelRFLGinUr0L72bPftg26CyPTuyLftkGNLoYiMc29J3rYUCxwkC7l1xIw3O5z6cR0NXMDlZ/jfi/AW5gGEFL5x@nC9N2nQ@vYfcc1v2cOAidXydSXiTsJGwFgL/C0tzXI3TEw)

Explanation:

```java
String s(int w, int g, int c, int m) {
    String b = "";
    int i = -g - c, j;              // i is the layer
    for (; i++ < g + m;) {          // Repeat (G+C+M+G) times, starting from -g-c to m+g 
                                    //Layer 0 is the last chocolate layer
        
        for (j = 0; j++ < w;) {     // Repeat W times
            b += 
                i <= -c | i > m ? 'G': //If before the chocolate or after the marshmellow, output a G
                i <= 0 ? 'C' :      // Else if equal or before last chocolate layer output C
                'M';                //Otherwise output an M
        }
        b += "\n";
    }
    return b;
}
```

Comment: [Not bad...for Java!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/116772/make-me-a-smore/116984#comment285597_116903)

Answer (score 1):

## JS (ES6), 111 bytes

```
n=`
`,G="G",C="C",M="M",r=(s,t)=>s.repeat(t),(w,g,c,m)=>r(r(G,w)+n,g)+r(r(C,w)+n,c)+r(r(M,w)+n,m)+r(r(G,w)+n,g)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Convex](https://github.com/GamrCorps/Convex), 20 bytes

```
"GCM"f*]z{~N+*}%(_@@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/convex#@6/k7uyrlKYVW1Vd56etVauqEe/g8P///2hjBSMFw9j/hgYA)

Answer (score 1):

## JS (ES6), 87 bytes

```
x=(w,g,c,m)=>(f=>f`Gg`+f`Cc`+f`Mm`+f`Gg`)(([[x,y]])=>(x.repeat(w)+`
`).repeat(eval(y)))
```

`x` acts as a standalone lambda function. The result has a trailing newline.

Try in a snippet:

```js
x=(w,g,c,m)=>(f=>f`Gg`+f`Cc`+f`Mm`+f`Gg`)(([[x,y]])=>(x.repeat(w)+`
`).repeat(eval(y)))

function doTheThing() {
  document.getElementById("target").innerText = x(
    document.getElementById("width").value,
    document.getElementById("graham").value,
    document.getElementById("chocolate").value,
    document.getElementById("marshmallow").value,
  )
}
```

```html
Width: <input id='width' value='10'>
Graham: <input id='graham' value='3'>
Chocolate: <input id='chocolate' value='2'>
Marshmallow: <input id='marshmallow' value='1'>
<pre id='target'></pre>
<button onclick='doTheThing()'>Do the thing</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 91 bytes

Includes trailing newline.

```js
f=

(w,g,c,m)=>(b=(`G`[r=`repeat`](w)+`
`)[r](g))+(`C`[r](w)+`
`)[r](c)+(`M`[r](w)+`
`)[r](m)+b

console.log(f(10,3,2,1))
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript ES6, <s>69</s> <s>68</s> 66 bytes

Thanks @Arnauld for golfing off one byte

```javascript
a=>b=>"GCMG".replace(/./g,(c,i)=>`${c.repeat(a)}
`.repeat(b[i%3]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/javascript-node#S7P9n2hrl2Rrp@Tu7OuupFeUWpCTmJyqoa@nn66jkayTqWlrl6BSnQySSE0s0UjUrOVKgHGSojNVjWM1Nf8n5@cV5@ek6uXkp2ukaRgaaGpEG@sY6RiB5AA)

### Explanation

Receives input in curried format `(Width)([Graham,Chocolate,Marshmallow])`

Using `.replace(/./g,...)` replaces each character in the string `GCMG` with the return value from the function `` (c,i)=>`${c.repeat(a)}
`.repeat(b[i%3]) ``

`` `${c.repeat(a)}
` `` creates each line of the graham cracker with a newline appended
`.repeat(b[i%3])` repeats this line the required number of times

Comment: Using `replace()` would save a byte: `a=>"GCMG".replace(/./g,(c,i)=>\`${c.repeat(a[0])}\n\`.repeat(a[1+i%3]))`

Answer (score 1):

## Java 11, <s>226</s> <s>171</s> 132 bytes

```java
(w,g,c,m)->{x(w,"G",g);x(w,"C",c);x(w,"M",m);x(w,"G",g);};void x(int w,String c,int x){for(;x-->0;)System.out.println(c.repeat(w));}
```

-55 bytes thanks to *@ceilingcat*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##TU8xbsMwDNzzCsKTBNBC0o5Cs3TolCwZiw4qowhKbdmQlNiF4be7jOKhy5FHHO54V3M39fX8s1BjUoKD8WHaAPiQbbwYsnB8UIB7589Agu8w4ANdQSrYSs2iecNwhABvsIgBHRK2st5PI5Pqo0IndVnfK6R1PVQs0f8Esy5B4xp0ytEHt6aMcrp0UeixrvdbLU@/KdtWdbeselblJghS0fbWZDFItlr4nf723XiClE3mUbxbriiexp9fYKJL8lkx2KH0F1IFRWK3xVd8wd3abV7@AA)

**Explanation:**

```java
(w,g,c,m)->{            // Main method with four integer parameters and String return-type
  x(w,"G",g);           //  Print all Graham rows
  x(w,"C",c);           //  Print all Chocolate rows
  x(w,"M",m);           //  Print all Marshmallon rows
  x(w,"G",g);}          //  Print all Graham rows again

void x(int w,String c,int x){
                        // Separated method with two integer & character parameters and
                        // String return-type
  for(;x-->0;)          //  Loop `x` amount of times:
    System.out.println( //   Print with trailing newline:
      c                 //    The given character `c`
       .repeat(w));}    //    repeated `w` amount of times
```

Comment: Not bad...for java!

Comment: @programmer5000 Hehe, thanks! I like golfing in Java 7 (and sometimes 8), although I don't think it will ever even compete with other answers.. The only time 'somewhat competed' with a Java answer was with [this 8 byte answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/113451/52210) and [this 19 byte answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/113359/52210), actually outgolfing Python for the first time. ;p Although those golfing languages with their 1 or 2 byte submissions still leave Java in the dust of course.

Comment: @ceilingcat Thanks! This is a pretty old answer, so going from Java 7 to Java 11 saves a bunch more bytes. ;)

Answer (score 1):

## F# (<strike>148</strike> 99 bytes)

```
let s w q="GCMG"|>Seq.iteri(fun i c->for j in 1..(q|>Seq.item(i%3))do printf"%A"("".PadLeft(w,c)))
```

Usage:

```
s 10 [2;3;4]
```

Ungolfed:

```
let smores width quantities =
    "GCMG"
    |>Seq.iteri(fun i char ->
        for j in 1..(quantities|>Seq.nth(i%3))
            do printf "%A" ("".PadLeft(width,char)))
```

I'm still new to F#, so if I did anything weird or stupid, please let me know.

Comment: A link to F# would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

## Google Sheets, 103 Bytes

Anonymous Google Sheets worksheet formula that takes input from cells `A1,B1,C1,D1` and outputs a s'more to the calling cell

```
=REPT(REPT("G",A1)&"
",B1)&REPT(REPT("C",A1)&"
",C1)&REPT(REPT("M",A1)&"
",D1)&REPT(REPT("G",A1)&"
",B1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>32</s> 17 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{x#',/4#y#'"GCM"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/v7pCWV1H30S5Ulldyd3ZV6k22tDAWsPY2sjaUDP2/38A)

**Example:**

```
> {x#',/4#y#'"GCM"}[10;(3;2;1)]
("GGGGGGGGGG"
 "GGGGGGGGGG"
 "GGGGGGGGGG"
 "CCCCCCCCCC"
 "CCCCCCCCCC"
 "MMMMMMMMMM"
 "GGGGGGGGGG"
 "GGGGGGGGGG"
 "GGGGGGGGGG")
```

**Explanation:**

```
{x#',/4#y#'"GCM"} / solution
{               } / lambda function with implicit parameters x and y
        y#'"GCM"  / take input each-both (#') number "G", "C" and "M"
      4#          / 4-take, ("GGG";"CC";"M") -> ("GGG";"CC";"M";"GGG")
    ,/            / flatten list into string, ("GGG";"CC";"M";"GGG") -> "GGGCCMGGG"
 x#'              / width-take each (10#"G" -> "GGGGGGGGGG" etc)
```

**Notes:**

- -15 bytes as looking through other answers it seems acceptable to take parameters as `[width;(graham;chocolate;marshmallow)]`, which means I don't have to explicitly list the parameters to the function

Answer (score 1):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), <s>12</s> 11 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
GCMG｛²└＠＊×Ｐ
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=R0NNRyV1RkY1QiVCMiV1MjUxNCV1RkYyMCV1RkYwQSVENyV1RkYzMA__,i=JTVCMyUyQzIlMkMxJTVEJTBBMTA_,v=3)

Explanation:

```
GCMG     push "GCMG"
  {      for each character
   ²       push the counter.                     Stack: [(input2, input1), "G", 1]
    └      swap two items below ToS.             Stack: [(I1, I2), "G", I1, 1]
     @     get the counter'th item of the input. Stack: [(I1, I2), "G", I1[1] ]
      *    repeat horizontally.                  Stack: [(I1, I2), "G" * I1[1] ]
       ×   repeat vertically.                    Stack: [(I2, I1), I2 × "G" * I1[1] ]
        P  print that.                           Stack: [(I2, I1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 69 bytes

```r
function(n,u)cat(rep(strrep(c("G","C","M","G"),n),c(u,u[1])),sep="
")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcUxCoAwDADA3WdkSiCDxU3o5NDJF4iDhBZcYmmb90cdjmteohdTGfejqGwk18CWK/bR/gQhAcP22T8JiJVY0NiOcBJxzzXCBOQFw8zLGshf)

Trying this `strrep` function I just heard about... Probably a `intToUtf8` approach could do better than that.
Thanks @Shaggy for pointing an issue...fixing it saved 6 bytes.

Comment: There's only one layer of chocolate.

Comment: @Shaggy you just saved me 6 bytes, ty!

Comment: @dzaima it takes a width `n` and a vector of heights `u` which you can input as `c(g,c,m)`, [like this](https://tio.run/##FckhDoAwDEBRzzGq2qSCgZ5CoDgBQZBmSzBl2dbzlyFevvjVc/RsKv15FZWN5O5YU8HW6x9B2IFhG45hB2IlFjS2M1xE3FKJMAF5xjCPsfLCgcg/)

Comment: @Giuseppe oh. Really shouldn't ask questions about languages I don't know :p

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 11 bytes

```
`GCM`f*εǏf⁋
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCJgR0NNYGYqzrXHj2bigYsiLCIiLCIxMFxuWzMsIDIsIDFdIl0=)

```
`GCM`f      # "GCM" as a char list
      *     # repeat each by width
       ε    # repeat each by input size amounts
        Ǐ   # Append the first item
         f  # Flatten
          ⁋ # Join by newlines
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 14 bytes

```
#&>'GCMG'#~4&$
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT0F9TQFWysFdR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxTlnNTt3d2dddXbnORE0FIrhRkys1OSNfwdBAIU3BWMFIwRAivmABhAYA)

Takes input as `10 f 3 2 1` for the example test case.

```
#&>'GCMG'#~4&$
           4&$    Cycle the right side to length 4; [3 2 1 3]
   'GCMG'#~       Repeat each char of GCMG that many times; 'GGGCCMGGG'
#&>               Repeat each char `left side` times and stack them into a matrix
```

Answer (score 0):

### Mathematica 102 Bytes (100 Characters)

Heard the s'mores built-in isn't coming out til V12.

```
s=StringRepeat;StringReplace[s@@@({Characters@"GCMG",#/.#[[4]]->#[[1]]})<>"",x_:>x~s~#[[4]]<>"\n"]&
```

Pretty straightforward using the idea of building up a column first. Long function names waste 35 bytes.  The one box-looking symbol is actually a transpose character and will paste into Mathematica just fine.

Usage:
`%@{Graham, Chocolate, Marshmallows, Width}`
e.g.
`%@{3, 2, 1, 11}`

Answer (score 0):

### R, <s>117</s> 114 bytes

```
f=function(w,g,h,m){s=strrep;f=function(a,b)s(paste0(s(a,w),'\n'),b);G=f("G",g);cat(G,f("C",h),f("M",m),G,sep='')}
```

Explanation:

```
function(w,g,h,m){              #width, graham, chocolate, marshmallow
  s=strrep                      #repeats strings (for each layer)
  f=function(a,b){              #for a given layer
    s(paste0(s(a,w),'\n'),b)    #repeat the corresponding letter w times, then repeat that + a newline the corresponding number of times
  }
  G=f("G",g)
  cat(                        #print to console:
      G,                 #so repeat "G" w times, over g lines
      f("C",h),                 #etc.
      f("M",m),
      G,sep='')        #with no separation
}
```

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to @Giuseppe!*

Comment: This can be shortened to 97 bytes with a different approach:  `function(w,g,s,m)matrix(c(rep("G",w*g),rep("S",w*s),rep("M",w*m),rep("G",w*g)),g*2+s+m,w,byrow=T)`

Comment: That seems to output a matrix, which doesn't quite look like what the OP specified.

Comment: Removing the brackets throws an error, but great catch on the 3 bytes!

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 91 bytes

```
import Data.List
(#)=replicate
f w g c m=intercalate"\n"$map(w#)$g#'G'++c#'C'++m#'M'++g#'G'
```

Should be pretty self-explanatory. Since it was noted in a comment that character matrices are allowed, here's a **58 byte** version that returns a list of strings (one for each layer):

```
(#)=replicate
f w g c m=map(w#)$g#'G'++c#'C'++m#'M'++g#'G'
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <strike>30</strike> 26 bytes

```
"GCMG"¬mpU £XÄ pVgY)q1Ãm·q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@6/k7uzrrnRoTW5BqMKhxRGHWxQKwtIjNQsNDzfnHtpe@P@/oYFOtLGOkY5hLAA)

30-byte solution:

```
Y=VÆ'GpUÃ·[YWÆ'CpUÃ·XÆ'MpUÃY]·
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@x9pG3a4Td29IPRw86Ht0ZHhQI4zhBMBZPqCmJGxh7b//29ooGOsY6RjCAA)

Answer (score 0):

## T-SQL, 259 bytes

```
CREATE PROC S @ INT,@g INT,@c INT,@m INT,@b INT=0 AS SET @B=@G G:PRINT REPLICATE('G',@)SET @G-=1IF @G>0 GOTO G C:PRINT REPLICATE('C',@)SET @C-=1IF @C>0GOTO C M:PRINT REPLICATE('M',@)SET @M-=1IF @M>0GOTO M Q:PRINT REPLICATE('G',@)SET @B-=1IF @B>0 GOTO Q RETURN
```

This stored procedure loops for the first layer or graham, chocolate, and Marshmallow with a `GOTO` in order to print up to the established amount. For the last layer of graham the fourth optional parameter (previously setted to the @g value) is used to do the same as the first layer of graham. The width of the layer is created with the `REPLICATE` function.

Usage:

```
EXECUTE S @ = 5, --Width
    @g = 7, --Graham
    @c = 8, --Chocolate
    @m = 4, --Marshmallow
    @b = NULL --Control variable, can be ignored
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 23 bytes

```
↷²Ｎγ×⟦⁺⁺⁺×Gγ×CＮ×MＮ×Gγ⟧Ｎ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/charcoal#@/@obfuhTe/3rDu3@fD0R/OXPWrcBUGHp7uDhJyBUoen@4JJoMCj@cuBzP//jRWMFAwVDA0A)

Input is in the form `graham`, `chocolate`, `marshmallow`, `width`

### Explanation

```
↷²                          Pivot right by 2 * 45 degrees
  Ｎγ                       Input number to g
      ⟦⁺⁺⁺×Gγ×CＮ×MＮ×Gγ⟧   "G" * g + "C" * input number + "M" * input number + "G" * g
     ×                   Ｎ Multiplied by N
```

Lists are implicitly printed joined by newlines.

Comment: I think you can save a byte by inputting `×GＮ` to `γ` and another byte by using `↓` instead of `↷²`. (Note that the existing code no longer works because `×` now vectorises but you can concatenate a newline for the same byte count.)

Answer (score 0):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
GCM”{e*.∙Q≥
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=R0NNJXUyMDFEJTdCZSouJXUyMjE5USV1MjI2NQ__,inputs=MTAlMEEzJTBBMiUwQTE_)

Explanation:

```
GCM”         push "GCM"
    {        for each
     e*        multiply horizontally by e, which, when first called, gets the numerical value of the next input
       .∙      multiply vertically by the nest input
         Q     output without popping and without disabling implicit output
          ≥    put the top item of the stack at the bottom as to keep the first item on the top
```

Comment: wasn' sogl v0.12 released after this challange?

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista Yes, but that's now [allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12882/59183).

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-R`, 16 bytes

```
"GCMG"ËpU*VgEÃòU
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=IkdDTUciy3BVKlZnRcPyVQ==&input=MTAKWzMsMiwxXQotUg==)

---

### Explanation

```
                     :Implicit input of integer U=Width & array V=[Graham,Chocolate,Marshmallow]
"GCMG"               :String literal
      Ë              :Map each character at index E
       p             :  Repeat
        U*           :   U multiplied by
          VgE        :   Get the integer at index E in V (Yay, index wrapping!)
             Ã       :End mapping
              òU     :Split to an array of strings of length U
                     :Implicitly join with newlines and output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>14</s> 12 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
…GCMS×ĆIĆÅΓ»
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9vc2FiaWX//@KApkdDTVPDl8SGScSGw4XOk8K7//8xMApbMywyLDFd)

**Explanation:**

```python
…GCM          # Push string "GCM"
    S         # Convert it to a list of characters: ["G","C","M"]
     ×        # Repeat each the (implicit) input-integer `w` amount of times as string
              #  i.e. w=4 → ["GGGG","CCCC","MMMM"]
      Ć       # Enclose this list; appending its own head as trailing item
              #  → ["GGGG","CCCC","MMMM","GGGG"]
       IĆ     # Push the second input-list, and enclose it as well
              #  i.e. [3,2,1] → [3,2,1,3]
         ÅΓ   # Run-length decode, repeating the strings the integers amount of times
              #  → ["GGGG","GGGG","GGGG","CCCC","CCCC","MMMM","GGGG","GGGG","GGGG"]
           »  # And join this list by newlines
              #  → "GGGG\nGGGG\nGGGG\nCCCC\nCCCC\nMMMM\nGGGG\nGGGG\nGGGG"
              # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```